# How can I create a matrix/array from a txt file?

Tags: python, arrays, regex, matrix

```
kinetic_e = open('t.dat.txt', 'r')
print kinetic_e

p_word = re.compile(r'\S+')
for line in kinetic_e:
    m = re.findall(p_word, line)
    print m
```

The file in question: http://sirius.chem.vt.edu/~crawdad/programming/project3/h2o_sto3g/t.dat...the first 2 columns have numbers 1-7 which I want for the dimensions of the matrix. Column 1 and 2 specify the row/column number for the numbers in the 3rd column.(Example: first row is row1,col1 then row2,col1 etc.)

My question: Am I on the right path to solving this and can I use regex to get through this problem? I'm having trouble finding sources to do this to create a 7x7 matrix with all the data

Comment: Did you try `np.loadtext()` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, wrong path. No need for regex here. Initialize a 7x7 2D-array. Loop throug the lines, split them, extract the i,j indexes from the first two columns and set the value of the 2d array with the third field:

```
matrix = [[0 for i in range(7)] for j in range(7)]
with open('t.dat.txt', 'r') as source:
    for line in source:
        i, j, value = line.split()
        i, j = int(i), int(j)
        matrix[i - 1][j - 1] = float(value)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without regular expressions. The data is already in a easily manipulated state as it is. You'll want to loop for each line in the file and just use the split method by the looks of it.

As far as mapping the rows and columns, you could stick a Python list inside of another (making sure the lists are of the correct sizes for list assignments) or doing the same thing with dictionaries so you don't need to worry about the sizes. Whichever one you choose for this, you can just do the assignment per row in your loop to get all the lines.

**Edit**

Seems like Bernhard above was a little quicker than me on the reply.